# why is the error of Undefined symbol detected in semantic analysis?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation

According to me ,An undefined symbol should be detected in parsing phase since after token is made in the lexical phase , then its type is undefined and if we try to assign a value to that undefined symbol , then how is the parse tree constructed without any error ?

```
int a;
b=19;
```

Here , the for symbol b , token has already been generated by the lexical analyser and value is as well associated with it , so what is done in the parsing phase due to which the undefined symbol is not detected in this phase ?

Comment: "semantic analysis" has no precise meaning in real compilers, which are *much more complex* than what you have been taught. BTW, several C compilers are free software, you might run them step by step in a debugger and observe when exactly they catch such an error

Comment: There's really no way anyone can give you a good answer without a lot more information, such as the entire code base your semantic analyzer is being used on.  And the version of the C standard in use is also very important - older versions of C were very liberal in allowing implicit declarations, so what used to be clearly-defined code often won't even compile under later versions of the standard.

Comment: Scope plays a role, the b variable could be a local variable, the name of a function parameter, a global variable, an extern declaration.  Generally resolved after building the AST, ymmv.